# Увешенный или увешанный?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, орфоэпия

***Увешенный или увешанный?***

Собственно, это и есть вопрос. Или это разные слова?

Хорошо бы убедительную ссылку, а то есть разные версии нормативности в словарях, тем более - Интернете.

Comment: Ёлка была увешена развесистой гирляндой и увешана игрушками. Гирлянда была, соответственно, развешена на ёлке, по ветвям которой были развешаны игрушки. Получилась  ёлка, увешенная гирляндой и увешанная игрушками. Хороших ссылок нет, но встречающееся рациональное зерно в том, что есть предметы, которые можно развесить в одном экземпляре (сеть) и предметы, которые можно развешать (допустимо и "развесить" их совокупность) по разным местам (картины).

Comment: Замените *у-* на *об-*, и вопрос исчезнет сам собой.

Comment: @V.V. *Замените у- на об-, и вопрос исчезнет сам собой* - каким образом исчезнет? Я же не корректор, не текст правлю, меня интересует именно это слово. Есои Вы имеете в виду "вопрос прояснится", то да согласен, обвешенный и обвешанный имеют право быть и различия в них хорошо видны. Но тут morkovkin уже сформулировал то, что я искал. Путает смешение двух глаголов в их просторечном употреблении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niemand прав, только не всё писал по существу.

**Увешанный** от увешать - из "вешать" = делать висящим/висячим.
**Увешенный от** "увесить" = "обвесить" из "весить = иметь вес.

Сложность в том, что эти значения часто смешивают.
**"Увесить"** сейчас почти забыто, что не делает его менее нормативным. Зато есть просторечное "увесить" = "увешать", поэтому и появляется не совсем нормативная форма **"увешенный"** - чем-то висящим, а не взвешенный"..

С другой стороны, есть разговорное "**вешать"** = "взвешивать", она тоже порождает, правда совсем редко, "увешать" = "взвесить все", "полность. совершить акт взвешивания" (ср. "уделать", "украсть") и от него **"увешанный"** - с неправильным значением.

Отсюда разнобой в словарях, хотя в главном, в нормативных значениях, они сходятся.

Answer (score 3):

Из толкового словаря на Грамоте.ру:

УВЕШАТЬ, увешанный;  кого-что чем. Вешая, покрыть, закрыть что-л. (сплошь или на большом пространстве, во множестве). У. стену фотографиями. У. комнату коврами.

УВЕСИТЬ, увешенный;  св. кого-что чем. Разг.-сниж. =Увешать.

Получается, что, согласно словарю,  увешать и увесить имеют одинаковое значение, но увешать - это нейтральный стиль, а увесить - разговорный стиль. Но такое стилевое различие желательно объяснить, и сделать это можно, связав, например, с разными суффиксами.

Суффикс И  часто имеет значение однократного  действия (навесить полку, выстрелить, застрелить, а суффикс А/Я -  значение многократного (избыточного) действия (навешать игрушек, настрелять, обстрелять).

Поэтому в слове увешать "правильный" суффикс А (многократное, избыточное действие), а в слове увесить "неправильный" суффикс И (однократное действие).

Из Нацкорпуса:

**1) Увешенный (3 примера):** знаменитый сумасшедший с улицы Горького, увешенный орденами; большой зал, весь увешенный огромными зеркалами; старый, опытный лошак, увешенный множеством погремушек.

**2) Увешанный (170 примеров):** Лес гремел, словно увешанный консервными банками, и слепил глаза огненными каплями смолы (Василий Аксенов). Рядом стояла Палатка Героев ― увешанный разноцветными щитами шатер с конским хвостом на вершине (Виктор Пелевин).

**И ни одного примера, связанного с весом.** Скорее всего,  в этом значении слово сохранило только терминологическое значение.

Comment: И Вам не режет слух это "увешенный "в этом значении? только три примера тоже о чем-то говорят.

Comment: Слух слово  "увешенный" не режет, так как увешенный и увешанный произносятся практически одинаково (краткий твердый гласный неопределенного качества). Что касается зрения, то тоже не слишком бросается в глаза, возможно, это связано с тем, что существуют  причастные формы с суффиксом ЕНН (завешенный, занавешенный). Также пара развешанные (нейтр.) и развешенные (разг.), для них в Нацкорпусе такое соотношение: 144 и 43.

Answer (score 1):

Увешанный - от *увешать*, увешенный - от *увесить*.

[http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=увешанный](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)

Или подвох?

Answer (score 1):

Можно ориентироваться по Далю,который различает разные глаголы :*увешивать-увешать-увешанный* (в смысле:повесить что‐то на что‐то ) и *увешивать-увесить-увешенный* (обмануть при взвешивании)

> УВЕШИВАТЬ, увешать что, чем, обвешать, развешать вещи на чем, повесить вещи, для удобства или красы, на что. Увешать стены картинами, оружием. Охотники воротились увешанные дичью. Он весь увешан орденами. —ся, страдат. и возвр. по смыслу речи. Увешиванье длит. увешанье окончат. действ. по глаг. Увешиватель, увешатель, увешавший что, кого-либо. || Увешивать, увесить чего, чем, или насколко, обвешивать, обманывать весом, недовешивать. Он увесил товару на целый пуд; увесил целым пудом. /| Увешиванье, увешенье, увес, увеска, действ. по глаг. || Увес, обрыв, обвал, круть. || Увес, количество, на сколько чего увешено; обвес, провес. Увесок, обвесок, вещь неполного веса.

Answer (score 0):

УвешАнный!!
От слова ВЕШАТЬ. Суффикс -АТЬ. А так как это страдательное причастие прошедшего времени, то суффикс -ать заменяется -а-нн-. Вот!

Comment: Увешенный или увешанный? Собственно, это разные слова? (См. вопрос.)

Comment: Или от слова "(у)весить".  Вы хоть бы вдумались в вопрос прежде чем говорить про страдательное причастие.